# Can I create index on a table in a MySQL database while in use

Tags: mysql, index, concurrency

And if I can, any reason (performance/stability) why I shouldn't?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that if your table is using the [InnoDB Plugin storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/index.html) (which I highly recommend), if it's a secondary index (almost surely the case), you can still [read from the table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-create-index-concurrency.html) (i.e. it's non-blocking to `SELECT` statements).

Comment: MySQL 5.6 update (feb 2013): you can now read and write to the table with online DDL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html

Comment: @MorganTocker several years later, but your link is now broken...

Answer (score 16):

Yes you can. It will lock the table you're adding an index to while it's being created. If the table is large, it may take awhile as it has to read each row while building the index.

Comment: Facebook has a solution for doing this online. Haven't tried it out myself: https://www.facebook.com/notes/mysql-at-facebook/online-schema-change-for-mysql/430801045932